# column with relationship count Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to add a column in my crud tables where the count of a relationship will be shown (just an integer).
I have a crud table of categories and I want to be able to see how many products there are in each category.
Is there any way to do it or is it something I need to implement on my own?

Comment: There is no need any packages for this. You just need to code this. I think Its not so complicated. Just try something and ask for help.

Comment: I'm using the `backpack`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a Category model, a Product model, and proper relationships defined between them, you should be able to:

- create [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for the count on the Category model:

`public function getProductsCountAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->products()->count();
    }`

- add a `text` column to your CRUD that uses the accessor defined above, just like it were a column in your database: `$this->crud->addColumn('products_count')`;

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you want to change the name of the colunm you can also do this: 
$this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'products_count', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Products']);

Answer (score -1):

[Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) provides a really easy way to deal with relationships and databases.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships).

You will have to create a pivot table where you can reference each product and link it to each category.

So, to answer your question, yes there is a way to do it and not having to deal with mySQL statements but you will have to search and implement it by yourself using Eloquent ORM.

Comment: I know how to do this within laravel, but not how you do it inside BACKPACK

Comment: Please edit your question to show the community what's your problem exactly, what you already tried (with code examples), what are you expecting to achieve. That way will be easier for others to help you and you are showing respect to them. Otherwise, you could just read the documentation. [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)